# Unable to extract Regional and Language Settings from Graph API Beta

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

[Graph API Explorer response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7q2O.png)The requirement is to extract regional and language settings for the signed in user. I have explored the Internet and found that we have to use Graph API Beta version to achieve this. I have used the same.
I can see the result in "Graph Explorer" web application, but it throwing "Null" values in my local c# application.

internal class Program
{

```
        private static IConfiguration _configuration;
        private static string _tenantDomain;

        private static string[] _graphScopes = new string[] { $"user.read", "user.readwrite.all", "user.read.all" };


        /// <summary>
        /// The access token for MS Graph
        /// </summary>
        /// NOTE: Do not use in prod apps as-is. you should be using a cached token obtained via MSAL. See aka.ms/aadcodesamples for a sample matching your app type and authN scenario
        private static string _GraphAccessToken = string.Empty;

        private static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            LoadConfig();

            // Prepare an authenticated MS Graph SDK client
            GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = GetAuthenticatedGraphClient();

            // Call Graph APIs

            // Get information from Graph about the currently signed-In user
            Console.WriteLine("--Fetching details of the currently signed-in user--");
            await GetMeAsync(graphServiceClient);
            Console.WriteLine("---------");

            /*Console.WriteLine("--Listing all groups this user is a member of--");
            var groups = await GetUserGroupMemberships(graphServiceClient);
            groups.ForEach(u => Console.WriteLine(u.DisplayName));
            Console.WriteLine("---------");

            Console.WriteLine("--Listing all directory roles this user is a member of--");
            var roles = await GetUsersDirectoryRoles(graphServiceClient);
            roles.ForEach(u => Console.WriteLine(u.DisplayName));
            Console.WriteLine("---------");

            //The delta query example
            await GraphDeltaQueryExample(graphServiceClient);

            // Batching
            BatchRequestExample(graphServiceClient).GetAwaiter().GetResult();*/

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        /// <summary>Calls the /me and /me/directreports endpoints of Microsoft Graph using the MS Graph SDK.</summary>
        /// <param name="graphServiceClient">The graph service client.</param>
        private static async Task GetMeAsync(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
        {
            // Call /me Api
            Console.WriteLine($"GET {graphServiceClient.Me.Request().RequestUrl}");
            var me = await graphServiceClient.Me.Settings.RegionalAndLanguageSettings.Request().GetAsync();
        LocaleInfo local = me.DefaultRegionalFormat;
        
            Console.WriteLine($"Default Regional from /me->{local.DisplayName}");

            // /me/directReports
            Console.WriteLine($"GET {graphServiceClient.Me.DirectReports.Request().RequestUrl}");
            var directreports = await graphServiceClient.Me.DirectReports.Request().GetAsync();

            foreach (User user in directreports.CurrentPage)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Direct report's Display Name ->{user.DisplayName}");
            }
        }



        private static void LoadConfig()
        {
            // Using appsettings.json as our configuration settings
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
             .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

            _configuration = builder.Build();
            _tenantDomain = _configuration.GetValue<string>("TenantDomain");
        }



       

        /// <summary>
        /// An example of how to authenticate the Microsoft Graph SDK using the MSAL library
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedGraphClient()
        {
            string GraphApiEndpoint = _configuration.GetValue<string>("GraphApiEndpoint");
            IPublicClientApplication app = BuildPublicClientApp();

            GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient =
                    new GraphServiceClient(GraphApiEndpoint, new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
                    {
                    // Retrieve an access token for Microsoft Graph (gets a fresh token if needed).
                    await AuthenticateUsingMsalAsync(app);

                    // Add the access token in the Authorization header of the API request.
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _GraphAccessToken);
                    }));

            return graphServiceClient;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the MSAL's IPublicClientApplication from the configuration
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static IPublicClientApplication BuildPublicClientApp()
        {
            PublicClientApplicationOptions appConfiguration = _configuration.Get<PublicClientApplicationOptions>();
            string authority = string.Concat(appConfiguration.Instance, appConfiguration.TenantId);

            // Building a public client application
            IPublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(appConfiguration.ClientId)
                                                    .WithAuthority(authority)
                                                    .WithRedirectUri(appConfiguration.RedirectUri)
                                                    .Build();

            return app;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Acquiring token for Graph using the MSAL SDK
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="app">The IPublicClientApplication instance.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">Failed to obtain the JWT token for Graph</exception>
        private static async Task<string> AuthenticateUsingMsalAsync(IPublicClientApplication app)
        {
            // Warning: This does not check for expired token and other relevant conditions.
            // In production apps, you will always use token cache instead of using variables like below here.
            // Use code samples ajaka.ms/aadcodesamples for your applicable app scenario
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_GraphAccessToken))
            {
                return _GraphAccessToken;
            }

            var GraphResult = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(_graphScopes).ExecuteAsync();

            if (GraphResult == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token for Graph");
            }

            _GraphAccessToken = GraphResult.AccessToken;

            return _GraphAccessToken;
        }

       
    }
```

Error Iam getting in Code:

*System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

local was null.*

In actual the value is not Null. When I open it via Graph API explorer I get response attached in image:
URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/settings/regionalAndLanguageSettings

I was trying to Fetch the Regional Language Settings but it doesn't shows in my C# application.
Iam using Graph Beta API.

Taken help from below URL:

[https://gist.github.com/kalyankrishna1/997f7ca1af1f73f8107c1c8cebfbaf3f`](https://gist.github.com/kalyankrishna1/997f7ca1af1f73f8107c1c8cebfbaf3f%60)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you may try to use the access token you used in `Graph API explorer` into your code and try if this token can help you call the api successfully. I think when you used that token it will help you solve your issue.

I had a test in my side with client credential flow to call this beta-version only api. See my code below.

```
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "your_tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "azure_ad_app_client_id";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var a = await graphClient.Users["user_id"].Settings.RegionalAndLanguageSettings.GetAsync();
```

[image]

I also had a try with integrate user login first, but I met some error which seem to relate to package `Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraphBeta`. So I only call the api successfully with client credential flow.

I also noted that you used `await graphServiceClient.Me.Settings.RegionalAndLanguageSettings.Request().GetAsync();`, but per my test, when I used beta version package, there's no `Request()`, that's why I used `.Settings.RegionalAndLanguageSettings.GetAsync()`. I think you may also need to check your packages. The screenshot below showed I used beta version.

[image]